# Convert American datetime to EU datetime in computer located in EU?

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

I get some datetime (ExactDate) from a db. These time are in US timezone, I need to convert them in EU TimeZone.

However if I use :

```
           ExactDate = (DateTime)dr["CREATE_DATE"];

           // change exact date to european time
           TimeZoneInfo info;
           info = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("US Mountain Standard Time");
           ExactDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(ExactDate,info);
```

The dates are not converted properly because my computer is seeing the `ExactDate` as an European date.

Do you know how I can solve this ?

Comment: I think you would need to use [`ConvertTimeToUtc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.converttimetoutc.aspx) and then local time for your current

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converting the date from the other TimeZone to UTC

like

```
ExactDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(ExactDate,info);
```

Once you have the corresponding UTC time you can get the European one later on using `.ToLocal`

Hope this is what you want.